# "Easy to adhere to" alternatives?

Tags: word-choice, idioms

Apparently "adherable" should not be used in formal language (if the opposite is true, please correct me).

Are there any more concise ways of saying "easy to adhere to", such as in this phrase:

For example:

> His workout routine was easy to adhere to.

As a side note, I think "easy to follow" is too ambiguous here, because it could mean "easy to read".

Comment: I think you underestimate a good word in *follow*: to remain devoted to or be in support of something. If it's a recipe or article, follow carries one meaning; if it's an exercise regimen, it carries a different meaning; if it's your dog, yet another meaning is implied.

Comment: @medica That may be so.  Good observation.  However, the same dilemma exists with *follow*: "followable" is not a word either.

Comment: **doable** is a single-word adjective, which is aparently what you are looking for. Otherwise, I am not sure why you are rejecting **follow**.

Comment: One would think that "sticky" would be perfect!

Comment: "Easy to follow" would work fine because the context of "workout routine" would preclude the reader from assuming that you meant it in the sense of "easy to read."

Comment: Easy to follow really is the most natural option.

Comment: Do you mean easy to perform according to plan, or easy to maintain as a habit? *Adhere* can mean either or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In describing a work-out routine, or other similar effort, "*Sustainable*" (literal meaning: "capable of being supported") would make an acceptable alternative to "*Adherable*".

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for "**easy to adopt**"?

> - adopt (verb) - To take and follow (a course of action, for example) by choice or assent: adopt a new technique. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/adopt)

Answer (score 0):

**Practicable** may be a good alternative. "His workout routine was practicable."

Comment: Please tell the OP what the word means, or in some other way explain why it is an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase *practical regimen* is very common.